# elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'request does not support [_source]')

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have this query:

```
range_query = {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "type": DEFAULT_LOG_TYPE
                        },
                        "match": {
                            "namespace": namespace
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                                "gte": ts,
                                "lte": te
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }, "_source": ["message", "@timestamp"]
    }
```

ad when I run these two commands on kibana, I can see that I have _source filed :

```
GET /my_index/_doc/doc_id and GET /my_index/_field_caps?fields=*&include_unmapped=true
```

Any idea why I get this error?
I also tried adding "docvalue_fields": ["message"] and I get the error :

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'parsing_exception', 'request does not support [docvalue_fields]')
```

Any idea to resolve the issue?

Comment: Also checking data mapping (es.indices.get_mapping(index=index)), I can see that this:
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {      
        "message": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword"
            }
          }
        },
        "source": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
            }
          }
        }, "@timestamp",
  ...        
      }
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your match clauses are not correctly specified, they should be like this:

```
range_query = {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "type": DEFAULT_LOG_TYPE
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "namespace": namespace
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": ts,
              "lte": te
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "message",
    "@timestamp"
  ]
}
```